# How can I have two tables A and B where B has all columns of A?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am currently building a CMS. I want to have a `page` table and a `page_revision` table, where `page_revision` has all columns of `page` + `rev_id` + `rev_parent_id`.

### MVCE

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Page(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pages'
    page_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.Text(), default='', nullable=False)

class PageRevision(Page):
    __tablename__ = 'pages_revisions'
    rev_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    rev_parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
```

The error I get when I try `flask db migrate`:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'pages' and 'pages_revisions'.
```

I was not sure what should happen. What I'm trying to do is to copy the structure, but I don't want inheritance in the OO sense.

Is there a way to copy all columns (make `page_id` NOT the primary key) without simply copy-and-paste?

Comment: Have you considered using a [mixin](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html)?

Comment: @IljaEverilä That sounds like exactly what I need! thank you! Do you want to make this an answer or should I create a community wiki answer (and attribute, of course)?

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a dirty hack and I'm not quite sure if it even works as expected but it might give some inspiration ;)

The idea is to create the PageRevision class dynamically by copying the fields of Page.

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()


class Page(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pages'
    page_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.Text(), default='', nullable=False)


def columns_of_table(table_type):
    for col in Page.__table__.columns:
        yield col.key, db.Column(col.type, default=col.default, nullable=col.nullable, primary_key=False)


PageRevision = type('PageRevision', (db.Model, ), {
    'rev_id': db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True),
    'rev_parent_id': db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True),
    **{key: col for key, col in columns_of_table(Page)}
})
```